# File upload in FLEX not allowing file of size greater than 1MB

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I am uploading a file using flex using Base64Encoder. but it is showing error when putting data on HTTPService as param when file size is more than 1MB. Please help in this. Thanks in advance.

Showing Following error:
Error: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032: Stream Error.

Function which I have written is as follows:

```
    protected function uploadButton_clickHandler(event:Event):void{
            try{
                var uniqueRowId:String=parentApplication.dg.dataProvider[parentApplication.dg.selectedIndex].UNIQUEROWID;
                var propObj:Object = parentApplication.propertyDict[uniqueRowId];
                fileRef = propObj["fileRef_"+uniqueRowId];

                fileRef.addEventListener(DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA,onUploadComplete);
                fileRef.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,onIOError);

                var selectedAttachment : String = propObj["selectedObjectStr_"+uniqueRowId];
                var UPLOAD_URL:String="/MDOSF/Customer_tab.do"; 
                var ext:String = selectedAttachment.substr(selectedAttachment.lastIndexOf("."), selectedAttachment.length);
                ext = ext.toLowerCase();                    
                var imgByteArr:ByteArray = event.target.data;
                var encoder:Base64Encoder = new Base64Encoder();    
                var totalBytes:uint = imgByteArr.length;
                var limitBytes:String = String((totalBytes/1024)/1024);
                var numericBytes:Number =Number(limitBytes);
                var decimal:String = numericBytes.toFixed(2);
                if(Number(decimal) > 1){
                    //Alert.show("Cannot upload file with size more than 1 MB","Message");
                    //return;
                }
                encoder.encodeBytes(imgByteArr);                    
                var params:Object = new Object();
                params.fileName = encodeURIComponent(selectedAttachment);
                params.ext = ext;
                params.file_data = encodeURIComponent(encoder.flush());
                params.action = "saveAttachment";
                params.GRID_PARAM = "fromGrid";
                params.selectedFile = encodeURIComponent(selectedAttachment);
                params.gridName = parentApplication.fieldName;
                uploadImageService.url = UPLOAD_URL;
                uploadImageService.send(params);

            }catch(err:Error){
            }
        }
```

Comment: is `uploadImageService` your HTTPService?

Comment: Server side, what are you using to process this request?

Comment: You should increase the POST limit on the server side

Comment: When I am using following line to send data, it works fine except in Firefox. Any Solution for this?


`fileRef.upload(new URLRequest("/MDOSF/Customer_tab.do?action=saveAttachment));`

Answer (score 0):

Most web servers limit `GET` [requests to 8KB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2659995/1856411) (but servers may very). By default, [`HTTPService` uses `GET` method](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/http/HTTPService.html#method). I'd recommend adding:

```
uploadImageService.method = 'POST';
```

Just before you call `uploadImageService.send(params);`, you'll also need to adjust your Java code to work with POST method over GET.

Comment: Its already mentioned in HTTPService:

<s:HTTPService id="uploadImageService" useProxy="false" result="onUploadComplete(event)" resultFormat="text"  showBusyCursor="true" method="POST"/>

Comment: Ah OK, I've suggested an edit for your original question to include that, since it's important to understand the scope of the problem.